# childrenWithProps: undefined JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  GalleryPhotosVideos.js
class GalleryPhotosVideos extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data3
            };
          }
        render (){
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>  
                React.cloneElement(child, {
                  albums: this.state.data3,
                })
             );
     return(
        <div style={galleryPhotos}>
                    {childrenWithProps}
        </div>
           )
        }
    }


 Content.js
     import { Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

     <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/albums"  component={Albums} />
         <Route path="/albums/:albumName" component={Album} />
         <Route path="/albums/:albumName/:photoId" component={Photo} />
    </Switch>
```

In this case I want to get photo albums and instead I get childrenWithProps: undefined
Nothing appears. In the original version in content there was  instead of  but using BrowserRouter did not work so I changed, but it did not give anything at all, or does anyone have any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `childrenWithProps` is an array of elements. you should use

```
return(
    <div style={galleryPhotos}>
                {childrenWithProps.map(childrenElement => childrenElement)}
    </div>
       )
```

So that your element will be rendered one by one with the prop.

Comment: I tried but there was information: "Can not read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Can you put a `console.log` and let me know what is inside your `this.props.children` while cloning it:?

Comment: {childrenWithProps: undefined}

childrenWithProps: undefined
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()

Comment: Please `console.log(child)` If there is no any child element childrenWithProps will be undefined

Comment: Line 75:  'child' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I can't understand the problem still can you please create a sandbox or codepen?

Comment: https://github.com/DanBuda11/react-photo-album
I used this repo and implemented it by changing it to my project

Comment: <div style={galleryPhotos}>
<Albums albums={data3}/>
</div>
when I use Albums, albums appear, but when I click on them, there are no photos inside, as if the component is empty even though the data3 table contains photos

Comment: I have an array, but I still do not have photos in the album :/ https://zapodaj.net/f64990c404d85.png.html